# Mass editing CSV files through command line?

Tags: csv, command-line, command

I have a huge list of CSV files in a certain directory.

I need to change the field for A1 on all the CSV files to this:  Email

Is there any way to do this all in one command to all the files?

**Or if this is easier:**  I just need `Email` to be the first line of each file so if there's a way to massively insert `Email` as the first line in each file that'll work perfect too!

Comment: What OS?  And do you mind using perl or python?

Comment: Perl works for me if possible.

Comment: Wait, is it insert or replace?

Answer (score 0):

Here's quick and dirty example for you:

```
replace="Email"
path="./"
ext="csv"

for f in $path*.$ext
do
    search=$(head -1 $f | awk '{print $1}')
    echo Changing: "$f"
    sed -i -e "s/$search/$replace/" "$f" && echo Done
done
```